# Is one allowed to sleep in a room/house where there are images of JC and other avodah zarah?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, christianity, contemporary-halacha

Is a Jew permitted to sleep in a room/house where there are idolatrous images on the walls, such as JC, etc.? What about non-Jews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dinonline ([here](http://dinonline.org/2019/05/06/staying-in-a-hotel-with-crucifixes/) and [here](http://dinonline.org/2019/04/30/is-one-allowed-to-sleep-in-a-room-with-christian-icons-which-are-being-worshipped/)) answer a very similar question

> Before getting into the technical halachic aspect if it is permitted
>   or not, it is surely not advisable to stay there when you are prone to
>   looking at idolatrous images on a constant basis. These things can
>   have an effect on us, and therefore it is best to try to correct the
>   situation or find somewhere else to sleep. **Having said that, it is not
>   halachically forbidden to sleep in the room, however you should
>   preferably not daven in that room**, and if you have no choice at least
>   it should not be facing the avoda zara. Additionally you should be
>   careful not to bend down to pick something up in front of it, as it
>   will look like you are bowing down to it.
>
> Sources: Shulchan Aruch O:CH 94-8, M:B 29-30, Chayei Adam 23-5

Answer (score -3):

1. Images/statues of people are not A"Z by itself, no matter what. You can have pictures of Rabbis and Moses and your grandfathers in your house.
2. What makes it A"Z is the fact that those are worshipped by different ways of worshipping an A"Z like in a church:

   - In a place where those pictures serve only as decoration, staying is permitted. Think about St. X hospital - lots of images that are not worshipped. My Grandma Z"l at 105 stayed in St. Louis hospital in Jerusalem for the last month of her life and it has a couple of statues inside.
   - In a place where those particular images *are* worshipped, it is forbidden to stay or visit (unless in a big need).
3. There's always a consideration of מראית עין - in any way don't let people think you're enjoying your stay.

Comment: 1) I'm fairly certain your first sentence is wrong. Without a source that an image like a cross is 'not A"Z by itself, no matter what', your claim sounds dubious. 2) 'In a place where those particular images are worshipped, it is forbidden to stay or visit (unless in a big need).' A"Z is one of the three that is Yehareg V'al Ya'avor. If this is forbidden due to A"Z, what difference does 'big need' matter?

Comment: @Salmononius2 1. I said, people, not objects. 2. Worshipping is YVY, not seeing. Like visiting a church is not YVY, it's just a Maris Eyn.

Comment: Bringing sources would definitely help

Comment: What makes you think images of saints and JC in Catholic hospitals aren’t worshipped? Hospital patients pray; in fact, some pray quite a lot. Do you think that if this patient room has been used by a person of that faith that they wouldn’t make some connection between their prayers and the image there? Even in a hallway, I saw people leave flowers to a statue of Mary. But if the room you are given has an idol in it, and you can’t have it removed, why are you not allowed to sleep there? Is this idol served by sleeping in its presence?

Comment: @alberko I think it might be a machlokes whether or not entering a church is YVY. I think I’ve read a ShuT on whether or not one can enter a church to literally save their life.

Comment: @Fei23 It can't be, see Rabmam's Yesodot Hatorah. Maybe one is a plumber or a technician. One needs to be worshipping explicitly. Rabbis might however, use allegories "as if it was YVY' or the like.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen It is pretty clear IMHO that all saints are messengers or agents, and not gods and praying to them and not different from ours "ברכוני לשלום מלאכי השלום" or hanging pictures of our Rabbis להבדיל. The only problem is with Josh, that some attribute other qualities.

Comment: @AlBerko there are those who don’t say ברכוני לשלום for this reason. Some who hang pictures of rabbis merely use them as inspiration/reminder to be better, not for prayer. Having a picture of the Chofetz Chaim next to your phone to remind you not to speak lashon hara isn’t the same as praying “Chofetz Chaim, pray for me to...”

Comment: My experience of those connected to saints is the latter *at best* if not actually asking the saint for things.